# Python: Perform prime test and binary conversion on NxN matrix

Tags: python

```
import math
import numpy as np
A = np.array ((range(1, 101, 1)), int)

R = A.reshape (10, 10)

for i in range (0, 10):
  for j in range (0, 10):
    if (R[i][j] % 2) == 0:
      R[i][j] = 0
    else:
      R[i][j] = 1

print (R)
```

The code is giving me a binary matrix but without checking for prime numbers.

Comment: You need to replace your even/odd check with a test for primality.  Where are you stuck?  A prime number checker is a trivial browser search, not to mention the many solutions already in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am not able to write code to check prime number within the 10x10 matrix.

Comment: I do not understand how the 10X10 matrix is a problem ? Cant you just create a method `def is_prime(n)` and then `if is_prime(R[i][j]): ` ?

Comment: You can simplify the looping by reshaping to a single array, convert to prime binary, then reshape to 10, 10.

Comment: ... an example is shown in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593080/6340496) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sympy.isprime()` function to check if number is prime or not

Code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import sympy

A = np.array ((range(1, 101, 1)), int)

R = A.reshape (10, 10)

for i in range (0, 10):
  for j in range (0, 10):
    if sympy.isprime(R[i][j]):
      R[i][j] = 1
    else:
      R[i][j] = 0

print (R)
```

You might need to install `sympy` using `pip install sympy`

Comment: thank you for ur reply, it solved my query in a way i could understand.

Answer (score 0):

How about something as simple as:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 101)
p = np.array([sp.isprime(i) for i in a]).astype(int)
p.reshape([10, 10])
```

Essentially, the difference is you are performing the prime test on an array, rather than the matrix. Once the test is complete, then reshape into the matrix.

If this is not an option, simply reshape the matrix into `[1, 100]` to perform the test, then reshape back into `[10, 10]`.

#### Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. As im new to python it will take some time for me to understand this.

Comment: @NageshPokle - No worries mate.  Basically, the 10x10 shape can be ‘flattened’ into a 1D array (e.g. `[1, 1, 0, 0, ... ]`).  Then it’s iterated using list comprehension, then reshaped back into 10x10.  Have a play, and it’ll start making sense.  Please upvote if it’s at all helpful, even to teach something new!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do a [simple sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) with just `numpy`. We need only check up to the square root of the upper bound (N * N = 100, N = 10).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

N = 10

def main():
    A = np.arange(1, N * N + 1)
    B = np.ones(N * N, int)
    # one is not a prime number
    B[0] = 0 
    for idx in A.flat:
        if idx > N:
            break
        for step in range(A[idx - 2], len(A) - idx, idx):
            B[step + idx] = 0
    print(B.reshape(N, N))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Nice.  Just a friendly tip: You can also use `np.ones(100, int)` to create the ones array. (It's ~3x faster)

Comment: thank you for your reply. As im new to python it will take some time for me to understand this.